# Template Class DLL C4251 Error

Tags: c++, templates, dll, compiler-errors

I'm writing a library to help simplify my development process in the future and as a part of that I have have written a wrapper for a char arrays, that has the same functionality as std::string's without the heap memory allocation. The class uses the definition:

```
template<size_t N>
class FString {
public:

    /* String functionality */

private:
    size_t mLength;
    char mString[N + 1];
}
```

I developed and tested the implementation in a separate solution and everything (appears at least to) work so I included it in my DLL project and added them to a number of my class definitions that are defined with the standard declspec import/export defines. I am able to build the project successfully, however my output is flooded with warnings along the lines of:

```
C4251 FString<260> needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class...
```

Without thinking I included my export/import macro thinking that would solve the problem. While the DLL project itself is able to build, my test project in the solution throws a number of errors wherever it is used:

```
C2491 FString<N>::append definition of dllimport function not allowed...
```

One of those occurs for every function I have that is not inlined. Looking into the error led me to MSDN where I found the cause of the error was because the entire class was templated and part of a single .hpp file, the definitions for the functions existed even if they are meant to be imported. This makes sense and I understand why this would be a problem.

The only way I've managed to solve the warnings and the errors is to include the import/export macro and inline every function. I'm not quite sure how 'inline' works with templated classes and functions but there are a few large functions that I would not normally want to inline. I realise this is more a a hint to the compiler then anything and may not actually inline all the functions, but I was hoping someone with more experience then I would be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks :)

Comment: You cannot export a template from a DLL. There's nothing to export - a template itself doesn't produce any machine code, not until it's instantiated and its parameters become known. You can however export particular specializations of a template, with a particular set of parameters.

Comment: Yes I've realised (remembered) that @IgorTandetnik, I was asking more about a way to remove the warnings and/or errors

Comment: You remove warnings and/or errors by not attempting to export and/or import a template.

Comment: Like i said in my original post, not including the export/import is what creates the warnings in the first place. My original assumption when creating this was you didn't need to for templated objects, which is why I was surprised and confused when they showed up

Comment: You need to export specific instantiations of the template, particularly those that are used by the (presumably non-template) class you are trying to export. You can, and likely should, export `FString<260>`.

Comment: Does your library has an exported non-templated class with a member of type `FString<260>`?

Comment: Yes i have a few around the place. Been mainly using them for filepaths at the moment